# Upgraded Seaborn 0.7.0 to 0.7.1, getting AttribueError for missing axlabel

Tags: python, seaborn

Having trouble with my upgrade to Seaborn 0.7.1. Conda only has 0.7.0 so I removed it and installed 0.7.1 with pip.

I am now getting this error:

`AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'axlabel'`

from this line of code

`sns.axlabel(xlabel="SAMPLE GROUP", ylabel=y_label, fontsize=16)`

I removed and reinstalled 0.7.0 and it fixed the issue. However, in 0.7.1, axlabel appears to still be there and I didn't see anything about changes to it in the release notes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes were made in 0.7.1 to clean up the top-level namespace a bit. `axlabel` was not used anywhere in the documentation, so it was moved to make the main functions more discoverable. You can still access it with `sns.utils.axlabel`. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Note that it's usually just as easy to do `ax.set(xlabel="...", ylabel="...")`, though it won't get you exactly what you want here because you can't set the size to something different than the default in that line.